# Fire a page view tag but only if it was from a specific referral URL. Google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a form that when submitted it goes to a different "success page" and I want to use that landing page to track conversions or count how many times people hit the "submit". I could use a page view tag but then that will fire every time someone goes to that page. So perhaps if someone hits the back button and reloads the page then that will count as a form submit.

So I would like to make a page view Tag in google tag manager that only fires if the page view is coming from a specific URL or referred from a specific URL. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Enable the built-in "referrer" variable, and on your target page create a trigger "`pageview`", with an added condition "`referrer equals <your referrer>`".

Some browsers might not send a referrer header, so this is not 100% reliable. If the page that sends the traffic is under your control, you might consider using a tracking parameter instead.